# Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted Python

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote a basic program in to create a socket with a server and a client. But the problem is that when I run the code, it gives me an error saying that only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted. So I think the problem is due to the port, I changed the port and it still don't work. How do I get this to work?

This is my code :

Server

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('localhost',3200))
sock.listen(1) 
print "Server is ready to receive data..."
client, address = sock.accept()
msg = client.recv(1024) 
print msg
```

Client

```
import socket
connection_to_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection_to_server.bind(('localhost',3200))
msg = raw_input("Please enter a content :")
connection_to_server.send(msg)
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding of how sockets work here.

The [`socket.bind()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind) call is used to bind to a particular port on a particular interface, the pair specified using a network address (bind to port `8080` on `127.0.0.1)`. You need to do this on the server side before you can start reading incoming data i.e "listening" on a particular socket. Only the server needs to do this. The client will then use [`socket.connect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) to connect to this socket.

As spectras pointed out in the comments, a bind is necessary when you need to communicate through a particular interface/port combination, which is almost always necessary for the server, but not always for the client. The client and server can't *both* have access/bind to the same port on the same interface, it makes little sense to do so.

Your client and server both try to start listening on the same socket, which is as the error message suggests, not allowed.

You should go through the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) before proceeding further.

Comment: Socket.bind does not start any listening, it just does what its name implies: binding the local side of the socket to a specific interface and/or port. It does have its use on clients sockets, for instance when the server expects incoming connections to come from a specific port. You can even call `sock.bind(('', 0))`, to force automatic assignation before connecting, in case you want to know which port you were assigned with `getsockname` before connecting.

Comment: Ah sorry, I intended to explain what was happening in this particular model, where the server has to bind to a socket before it can read any data coming into the socket for it's "listening". I'll modify to make it more technically correct/unambigous.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than

```
> connection_to_server.bind(('localhost',3200))
```

you should have

```
connection_to_server.connect(('localhost',3200))
```

Answer (score 0):

For SOCK_STREAM sockets, your client should connect, not bind. From the [Sockets HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html):

```
import socket
connection_to_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection_to_server.connect(('localhost',3200))
msg = raw_input("Please enter a content :")
connection_to_server.send(msg)
```